# Как сделать что бы нижний блок не выходил за границы основного блока CSS&

Tags: css

Как сделать что бы при вводе зеленый блок сжимался? А не тянул нижний синий блок блок вниз? Надо что бы при вводе текста в верхний синий блок зеленый не смещал нижний синий блок. А между двумя синими сжимался.

```css
 .block{
        width: 250px;
        height: 400px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    .t_block{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 50px;
        background: #1E90FF;
    }
    .back{
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        background: #a6e22a;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .back1{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="block">
<div class="t_block" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="back1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}

.t_block {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #1E90FF;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #a6e22a;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.back1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="back">
    <div class="t_block" contenteditable="true"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="back1"></div>
</div>
```